# Green Lizard Race Rebellion

Tags: story-identification, books, alien-invasion

There was a book that came out in the either late 80s to 90s I think. It was a sci-fi fantasy series. At least a trilogy. It was about a green lizard race that were either eradicated or turned slaves. The main character was a Lizard Princess and grew up side by side with a little girl from the competing race. I read the first book. In it, she gets kidnapped, beaten, abused and actually trained to be a warrior. She is forced to fight to the death at events. She never loses. She rises to fame and eventually, she leads a rebellion to take her world back.

Comment: You two asshats took the time to markup and edit my question,  it had absolutely nothing to add. Must be nice to have a god complex.